# Create or add random number to fulfill some condition

Tags: google-bigquery

I have data like this..

```
month_date  location  sales
2022-01-01  Asia      150
2022-01-01  Europe    250
2022-02-01  Asia      100
2022-02-01  Europe    100
```

and breakdown by day_date

```
day_date    location  sales
2022-01-01  Asia      12
2022-01-02  Asia      10
2022-01-03  Asia      15
2022-01-04  Asia      19
2022-01-05  Asia      15
2022-01-06  Asia      11
....
2022-01-31  Asia      2
total:      Asia      132
```

but when I compare sales between month_date=150 and day_date=132 I still have minus 18.
is it possible to add random data which contain minus 18 but breakdown by day_date?
like below

```
day_date    location  sales
2022-01-01  Asia      13
2022-01-02  Asia      11
2022-01-03  Asia      16
2022-01-04  Asia      20
2022-01-05  Asia      16
2022-01-06  Asia      12
....
2022-01-31  Asia      2
total:      Asia      150
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below. (*diff* number, 18 in this case, will be added by one starting from 1st day of month.)

```sql
SELECT day_date, location,
       sales + DIV(diff, days) + IF(EXTRACT(DAY FROM day_date) <= MOD(diff, days), 1, 0) AS sales
  FROM (
    SELECT d.*,
           m.sales - SUM(d.sales) OVER w AS diff,
           DATE_DIFF(LAST_DAY(month_date), month_date, DAY) AS days
      FROM day_table d 
      LEFT JOIN month_table m 
        ON DATE_TRUNC(d.day_date, MONTH) = m.month_date AND d.location = m.location
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC(day_date, MONTH), d.location)
  );
```

**Query results**

[image]